# Composer autoload with different (shorter) directory structure

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-0, psr-4

I want my PHP classes to be loaded by Composer. It works when I follow the directory structure, according to the namespaces.

For example, my class `\MyCompany\MyProject\Class1` is loaded when located in `src/MyCompany/MyProject/Class1.php`. I use this composer settings:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "MyCompany\\MyProject\\": "src/" }
}
```

However, I do not want to put **all** my files to MyCompany directory since it is the only one in src. I know Java does it like this, but still. Is there any way to set up Composer so it will load my classes when they are directly in src? For example from file `src/Class1.php`.

Edit: PSR-4 addresses directly this problem, although classmap still works (and it's recommended for production setup).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "src"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use PSR-4, especially if you have more than a few classes i.e.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "MyCompany\\MyProject\\": "src/" }
}
```

This should put you right where you want to be.  But, as was in my own experience, this may require some tinkering till you get it right.  See more here:  http://seld.be/notes/psr-4-autoloading-support-in-composer